# Javascript array of quarters in year to single year

Tags: javascript

How do I convert an array of quarters in a year to just a year if all quarters are present & else have quarters data as it is.
e.g. From array of year quarters like this

```
['1Q2017', '2Q2017', '3Q2017', '4Q2017', '1Q2018', '2Q2018', '3Q2018']
```

should have like this output

```
['2017', '1Q2018', '2Q2018', '3Q2018']
```

Comment: Have you even tried anything?

Comment: psuedo code: if 1q, & 2q, &3q, &4q exist, then delete, add year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var arr = ['1Q2017', '2Q2017', '3Q2017', '4Q2017', '1Q2018', '2Q2018', '3Q2018'];
    var mapped = {};
    var output = [];
    arr.forEach(v => {
      let sp = v.split('Q');
      if(!mapped[sp[1]]) { 
        mapped[sp[1]] = [];
      }
      mapped[sp[1]].push(sp[0]);
    });
    Object.keys(mapped).forEach( k => {
      if(mapped[k].length === 4) {
       output.push(k)
      }
      else {
       mapped[k].forEach(q => output.push(`${q}Q${k}`));
      }
    });
console.log(output);
```

`output` will have the required value.

Answer (score 1):

A short approach by checking the last quarter and checks if all quarters are in the result set. Then add the year instead of the years's quarters strings of a year.

Otherwise keep the quarter strings.

This approach requires a sorted data set.

```js
var array = ['1Q2017', '2Q2017', '3Q2017', '4Q2017', '1Q2018', '2Q2018', '3Q2018'],
    result = array.reduce((r, s) => {
        r.push(s);
        if ([4, 3, 2, 1].every((q, i) => r[r.length - 1 - i] === q + 'Q' + s.slice(2))) {
            r.length -= 4;
            r.push(s.slice(2));
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

---

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the years and a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for the quarters.

This approach requires a sorted data set.

```js
var array = ['1Q2017', '2Q2017', '3Q2017', '4Q2017', '1Q2018', '2Q2018', '3Q2018'],
    result = array.reduce((map => (r, s, i, a) => {
        var [quarter, year] = s.split('Q');
        if (!map.has(year)) {
            map.set(year, new Set);
        }
        map.get(year).add(quarter);
        if (quarter === '4' || i + 1 === a.length) {
            if (map.get(year).size === 4) {
                r.push(year);
            } else {
                r.push(...Array.from(map.get(year), q => q + 'Q' + year));
            }
        }
        return r;
    })(new Map), []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest approach I could think of:

```
let x = ['1Q2017', '2Q2017', '3Q2017', '4Q2017', '1Q2018', '2Q2018', '3Q2018']
let res = []

x.forEach((entry, index) => {

    let year = entry.substring(entry.length - 4)

    if (x.includes('1Q' + year) && x.includes('2Q' + year) && 
          x.includes('3Q' + year) && x.includes('4Q' + year)) {

        if (!res.includes(year)) {
            res.push(year);
        }
    }

    else {
        res.push(entry)
    }
})


console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [`contact()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/contact) and [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to get the required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const arr = ['1Q2017', '2Q2017', '3Q2017', '4Q2017', '1Q2018', '2Q2018', '3Q2018'];


let result = Object.entries(arr.reduce((r,v)=>{
 let key = v.split('Q')[1];
 r[key] =(r[key]||[]).concat(v);
 return r;
},{})).reduce((r,v)=>r.concat(v[1].length==4?v[0]:v[1]),[]);


console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
```